# Проблема с регистрацией Singleton в контекст QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, singleton

Пытаюсь подключить класс Singleton в контекст QML, который можно было бы использовать и в коде с++.Подключаю следующим образом.

Application.cppp

```
Application::Application(int &argc, char **argv) : QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(this);

    PropertySystem *propertySystem = PropertySystem::GetInstance(this);
    ExecAutoDiag *execAutoDiag = new ExecAutoDiag(this);
    ExecSwitchPowerSystem *execSwitchPowerSystem = new ExecSwitchPowerSystem(this);

    engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("PropertySystem", propertySystem);
    engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("ExecAutoDiag", execAutoDiag);
    engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("SwitchPowerSystem", execSwitchPowerSystem);

    engine->load(QUrl(QLatin1Literal("qrc:/Qml/MainWindow.qml")));
}
```

PropertySystem.cpp

```
PropertySystem *PropertySystem::GetInstance(QObject *parent)
{
    if (!propertySystemSingleton) {
        propertySystemSingleton = new PropertySystem(parent);
    }

    return propertySystemSingleton;
}
```

Но при запуске приложение получаю следующее сообщение

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: В каком месте падает?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin не могу даже продебажить. Сразу крашиться даже перед созданием главного объекта Application в фукции main.cpp

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а такой код вообще допустим?

Comment: Для добавления с++ классов в qml, нет и проблемы не в наследовании application, а в engine->rootContext()->...) вот так правильно https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Comment: Хотя, наследовать надо бы от QGuiApplication. Ну, короче, посмотрите пример из доки

Comment: сначала лоад, а потом сет контекст